# Creating complex SQL search query with JDBI

Tags: sql, select, search, jdbi

I am new to JDBI.  I have seen several simple examples of annotating a DAO with a query like "`Select * from tableName where id=?`".

Could someone point me to documentation for more complex queries such as searching by a dynamic list of parameters?  For example, a user can search by name, age, id, height, etc, but I am unaware until runtime which combination of these search parameters may come in to my search method.  I may not get a search value for age, and so do not need to bind anything to the search query for that.

Any pointers appreciated,
~Kim

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way I've seen of doing dynamic searches is to put each search criteria right in the query:

```
class MyParameters {
  UUID id;
  String name;
  OffsetDateTime createdAfter;
  // ... more parameters
  // (getters and setters elided)
}

interface MyDao {
  @SqlQuery("select * from tableName "
      + "where (:id is null or id = :id) "
      + "and (:name is null or name ilike (:name || '%')) "
      + "and (:createdAfter is null or created_on >= :createdAfter) "
      // etc
  )
  List<MyObject> listMyObjects(@BindBean MyParameters parameters);
}
```